# Rspec test failed when expecting ordered array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to learn RSpec using *Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec*.I am at the where I am trying to use `before :each do` to load variable before each test. The tests were working before but no longer pass as expected.

Here are the tests:

```
  describe "filter l_name by letter" do
    before :each do
      @flinstone = Recruiter.create(email:    'foobar@gmail.com',
                                    password: 'foobar',
                                    f_name:   'Fred',
                                    l_name:   'Flinstone',
                                    company:  'Picosoft')

      @francis = Recruiter.create( email:    'flubber@gmail.com',
                                   password: 'flubber',
                                   f_name:   'Frank',
                                   l_name:   'Francis',
                                   company:  'Rock Inc')

      @barney = Recruiter.create(  email:    'foobaz@gmail.com',
                                   password: 'foobaz',
                                   f_name:   'Barney',
                                   l_name:   'Rubble',
                                   company:  'Rock Inc')
    end 

    context "matching letters" do
      it "returns sorted array of results that match" do
        expect(Recruiter.by_letter('F')).to eq [@flinstone, @francis]
      end
    end

    context "non-matching letters" do
      it "returns sorted array of results that match" do
        expect(Recruiter.by_letter('F')).to_not include @barney
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the error I get:

```
(compared using ==)

       Diff:


       @@ -1,19 +1,19 @@
       -[#<Recruiter:0x000000086587b0
       -  id: nil,
       +[#<Recruiter:0x00000008560e70
       +  id: 1,
          email: "foobar@gmail.com",
          password: "foobar",
          f_name: "Fred",
          l_name: "Flinstone",
          company: "Picosoft",
       -  created_at: nil,
       -  updated_at: nil>,
       - #<Recruiter:0x0000000863aad0
       -  id: nil,
       +  created_at: Sat, 11 Apr 2015 18:38:31 UTC +00:00,
       +  updated_at: Sat, 11 Apr 2015 18:38:31 UTC +00:00>,
       + #<Recruiter:0x00000008560d08
       +  id: 2,
          email: "flubber@gmail.com",
          password: "flubber",
          f_name: "Frank",
          l_name: "Francis",
          company: "Rock Inc",
       -  created_at: nil,
       -  updated_at: nil>]
       +  created_at: Sat, 11 Apr 2015 18:38:31 UTC +00:00,
       +  updated_at: Sat, 11 Apr 2015 18:38:31 UTC +00:00>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clearing your database.

Comment: Can you tell me what is your rspec and Rails version?

Comment: RSpec 2.14.8
Rails 4.2.0

Comment: that worked, thanks a lot! I will accept it as the answer if you create it.